# Text & Horizontal Rules in Spoilers

Tags: bug, android-app, mobile-web, spoilers

When putting a horizontal rule (`<hr>`) inside a spoiler: On the android app, things as links or code blocks seem to be the only thing hidden in spoilers. On a mobile browser those things completely disappear, and when you click to show the spoiler, the normal text disappears.

---

<sub>The following pictures are screenshots of [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45875/the-mysterious-email-on-mithrandirs-puzzlers-mail/45877#45877) answer, but I also encountered this problem on other posts.</sub>

**Stack Exchange Android App (1.0.89):**

[image][image]

**StackExchange.com on mobile:**

[image][image]

Comment: Haha! More publicity for my question! :D :P