# Click to ... expand spoiler?

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

[image]

[Link to answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/12928/44061)

I saw a spoiler today and noticed that "Click to show spoiler" has in fact turned into "Click to view full content of spoiler", with all formatting and MathJax lost. This would be extremely counter-productive on sites like Puzzling.

Also, some text is missing even after expanding the spoiler.

Latest Chrome from Google Play, Android 7.1.

Comment: Because there's markup in the spoiler. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287127/text-horizontal-rules-in-spoilers