# Horizontal Rules in spoilers expose text without revealing

Tags: bug, status-planned, spoilers

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287127/text-horizontal-rules-in-spoilers) used to happen on mobile only. Now it also happens on desktop with the new spoiler tags. If the content of the spoiler contains `<hr>`, everything without markdown is visible without revealing the spoiler

[Link to post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45877/37714)

Image:

[image]

Comment: Taking a look into this now. Thanks for the report

Comment: So, the issue here has to do with how commonmark treats block html and a quirk in how we parse our custom`>!` syntax that doesn't make it 100% commonmark blockquote compliant. I have a strong feeling this is not due to the recent spoiler changes since the recent changes were css only and this is a parsing issue. I'm looking into it a bit more to confirm my suspicions.

Comment: While it's not strictly related to the [new editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor), we're going to look into this as part of that work. Thanks for the report!